# How to connect the output of the 555 in monostable mode to an optocoupler?

Tags: oscilloscope, timer, opto-isolator, 555, monostable

I currently have the following schematic for my circuit: [image]

Link to the [simulation](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjATCAMB00IQVhADlhVYCcB2JqquAzNmUikgGwiXS0CmAtGGAFBhUoTSrgAs-EMR4ChQ6GwDuIHnzC4ac2biiSZyhTS3hFs6bN6z+9SHwgmYBnTb0RVVgMa6lDnSPqnmuGPAT8ybCREAPJfBHYAcxdhUXdiGk82ACcY221IGHBEBGs9Vih7KAKrACU0U0zKtSzLFE9fJDYAeWEEwz4TemUk1LNwTP6LBrBEa0wB4vyqtmchy1Ruyy8mH35YVGpIMH4kBSDiXDBw6CjhaCFiC-PL0SSNN0zidpL1NoyoZ+09SVTFyYqxhGYxk-xK-VebAAzoCPIDhlljgAXZIAVwYeRocP+cMkJmIwio8kEIACSiMpmgAH0qPwqdT+MQkHS4DlFBBsKRdsRIEh6bAwPSqewTGt-giyUDwGxRaTxZZBOZLCLoGKlvQEkrTAZ+PKNe0EW8vlLjT0UoTzA5Ne9EWNotbjQ6iVk3khpp8XjMZNainLug5JNFaRqkFBg8JUBIrK1JUyoNQQzVXXYLLQ7MsDG6PmmlKnfiBw77w3HbblUkhsIUHIWA+BYE0ZFmVPHK82rDJY6GC5ZfXjVSAmOKHExdW32DJOG29e3wFjrji7ubB-6oCwJr3srkYSxMsod8UqA16AAzACGABsoRiZPuOgOhgGDMubgOce03s-jW-EgZv7DF6C1T3oMh5WAA9tk3a1KMah+Ag7Kctg3K8icCB4FwVAQPU0oQWABK0rUTIEqyiAIVySA8lhqHQOh1BUccxQEsQbAQSgBGmFh-CJHBoRBCEgT1HBDGyLQwgsbE4ATPQJjYHwJHwZhiHIVRcDHAS7AABYiT4TRAA).

On the simulation everything is working pretty good. The output of the 555 which is in monostable mode is giving around 5 volts at the output of the optocoupler after the 1.5 ohms. However when I am doing this circuit on the breadboard and seeing the output after the 1.5 ohm resistor, it is giving around 480 or 300 mV which is really odd. I am using a 4n36 optocoupler. I am not sure if I am connecting it incorrectly or if there is an impedance or discharge from this optocoupler that's sucking up almost all of the voltage.

(Btw the reason why I have an optocoupler after the output of the timer is because I will add a mosfet (hence the 1k resistor for the bias) whose gate will be connected to the output of the second optocoupler.)

Is there a way to get around 5 v at the output of the optocoupler irl somehow?

Comment: General questions: what is this a prototype for? Because in your current circuitry, the optocouplers don't serve their purpose: they do not galvanically isolate, as there's multiple connections between their sides, and even a shared ground.

Comment: I bet your simulation uses a drastically simplified model of an optocoupler. Have you verified the model parameters match the datasheet of the optocouplers you're actually using?

Comment: You write "the reason why I have an optocoupler after the output of the timer is because I will add a mosfet" - but that's not a reason to use an optocoupler. Just drive your MOSFET directly with the 555.

Comment: Why do you have a 1.5 ohm resistor in series with a 1K?  I'd suspect incorrect or faulty connections on the breadboard.

Comment: You don't really have sufficient drive (maybe Vf ~=2.5mA) to saturate the optocoupler, and nothing for the safety margin you should add for temperature, component variation and aging, but under typical conditions you should be getting more than a few hundred mV so maybe you've got a bad connection or the load resistor value is lower than you think. You might want to look at an isolated gate driver if that's what you need. The optocoupler will be rather slow.

Comment: @Marcus Müller The circuit is for a spark plug circuit. I agree that the optocouplers don't serve a purpose as of yet. The first one is placed so that it can receive a 5v signal from a bcc cable or a TTL input. The second one will be place to the gate of the mosfet to not allow the back emf or noise to pass through the entire circuit. I have also consulted the datasheet for the 4N36 optocoupler that I am using: https://www.vishay.com/docs/83717/4n35x.pdf. I am not sure why I am not getting around 5 V after the second optocoupler

Answer (score 1):

It maybe that the current transfer ratio is too low to generate enough output current to create a 5V drop across the 1k resistor at the output.

You could try increasing the value of the 1k output resistor to see if the output current will create a larger voltage drop across it.

Comment: 4N36 datasheet says minimum CTR is 100%. The 555 drops about 1.4V and the opto LED drops another 1.1V. That means the 1k resistor in series with it probably only has ~2.5V across it, so at 100% CTR the output would be ~2.5V. This doesn't explain the OP's very low output voltage, but the CTR is still marginal and needs to be addressed.